# Hot to get the parameterless constructor through Kotlin Reflection API?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-reflect

Given a domain class with a parameterless constructor, how do we get a reference to that constructor through the Reflection API?

Consider for example a `Student` data class, such as:

```kotlin
data class Student(var nr: Int = 0, var name: String? = null)
```

Notice, we can confirm the presence of the parameterless constructor through `javap` that shows:

```
public pt.isel.Student(int, java.lang.String);
    descriptor: (ILjava/lang/String;)V

public pt.isel.Student(int, java.lang.String, int, kotlin.jvm.internal.DefaultConstructorMarker);
    descriptor: (ILjava/lang/String;ILkotlin/jvm/internal/DefaultConstructorMarker;)V

public pt.isel.Student();
    descriptor: ()V
```

Yet, none of the following approaches returns the parameterless constructor:

- Approach 1 - `primaryConstructor`:

```kotlin
val constructor = Student::class.primaryConstructor
```

- Approach 2 - All constructors declared in the class:

```kotlin
// java.util.NoSuchElementException: Collection contains no element matching the predicate
val constructor = Student::class.constructors.first { it.parameters.isEmpty() }
```

---

Alternatively, we can proceed via Java Reflection that works fine, but it should not be necessary such detour:

```
val constructor = Student::class.java.getDeclaredConstructor()
```

---

Second, why do we need that? Because we want to instantiate a domain class at runtime. Yes, we know that [`createInstance()` of `KClass`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.reflect.full/create-instance.html) do that job. But it throws `IllegalArgumentException: Class should have a single no-arg constructor` if there is no parameterless constructor.

Thus, we would like to check before-hand if we could call the `createInstance()` with no exceptions.

Comment: "but it should not be necessary such detour" Why not? You only see the parameterless constructor if you use `javap`, which is a Java thing. That's unrelated to the Kotlin reflection API.

Comment: @Sweeper `createInstance()` is part of Kotlin Reflectionm API and it may claim `IllegalArgumentException: Class should have a single no-arg constructor`. All this in Kotlin! IMO, it should also provide a way in Kotlin to let me know if I can make a call to `createInstance()` without exceptions.

Comment: Are you confused why `createInstance` doesn't throw an exception for `Student`? Have you read its [documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.reflect.full/create-instance.html)? It also checks if the parameters are optional, not just whether the class has a parameterless constructor.

Comment: @Sweeper I am not confused about that. As I am clarifying at the end of OP: "_we would like to check before-hand if we could call the createInstance() with no exceptions._". I do not want to use a try/catch to check if the `createInstance()` works fine, or not, and if we have to choose a different way of instantiating dynamically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The parameterless constructor here only exists in the compiled Java class, and not in your Kotlin code. As far as Kotlin code is concerned, your `Student` class has one single constructor, with 2 optional parameters.

The Kotlin reflection API is designed to be platform-independent, so you have to use Java reflection to get the parameter constructor.

If you just want to see if you can call `createInstance` safely, you can just check if the class has a single constructor whose parameters are all optional. This is [documented](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.reflect.full/create-instance.html):

> Creates a new instance of the class, calling a constructor which either has no parameters or all parameters of which are optional. If there are no or many such constructors, an exception is thrown.

```
val isSafe = someClass.constructors.singleOrNull { 
    it.parameters.all(KParameter::isOptional) 
 } != null
```

This is similar to how `createInstance` is [implemented](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/6a670dc5f38fc73eb01d754d8f7c158ae0176ceb/core/reflection.jvm/src/kotlin/reflect/full/KClasses.kt#L274) to throw the exception.